# Attempt to assign property of non-object error

Tags: php

I am getting this error and i can't see what i am doing wrong. I have done the same thing with other objects from other classes which are built in the exact same way and i can't see why i am getting this error now.

The code in which i create the object is this one:

```
$consulta2 = "SELECT * FROM TiposDireccion WHERE Cliente_CIF='$cif' and Direccion_Direccion='$direccion' and Direccion_CP=$cp ";
                echo($consulta2."</br>");
                if ($resultado2 = $conexion->query($consulta2)){
                    while($fila2 = $resultado2->fetch_object()){
                        $tipodireccion78=$fila2->TipoDireccion_Tipo;
                        //we see here that the select is returning a correct string with a correct value
                        echo($tipodireccion78);
                        //we try to instantiate and it fails =(
                        $unTipoDireccion=TipoDireccion::constructor1($tipodireccion78);
```

This is the class TipoDireccion:

```
<?php

class TipoDireccion{

private $tipo;
private $descripcion;

//Construct auxiliar
function __construct() {

}

//Constructor 1 : completo
function constructor1($tipo) {

     $tipoDireccion = new TipoDireccion();

     $tipoDireccion->tipo = $tipo;

     return $tipoDireccion;
}

function ponTipo($tipo) {
    $this->tipo = $tipo;
 }

function devuelveTipo() {
     return $this->tipo;
 }

function ponDescripcion($descripcion) {
     $this->descripcion = $descripcion;
 }

function devuelveDescripcion() {
     return $this->descripcion;
}   

}
?>
```

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: Which line of code is associated with that error?

Comment: @Deele   this one: " $unTipoDireccion=TipoDireccion::constructor1($tipodireccion78); "

Comment: construction1 must be static function

Comment: @user345352353 Thank you! but I already tried that and it will still give the same error

Comment: @user3481909 I don't see reason within this code, why that code should output that error. Only error could be about loose script, that you are using (not using static/dynamic classes and public/private variables, as they should have been used, by strict standards). There could be something else, try `var_dump($fila2)` at the beginning of that loop.

Comment: Excuse, "construction1 must be static function" is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is still relevant to you, but in case anyone else comes on here for an answer.  The problem is in this function:

```
function constructor1($tipo) {
     $tipoDireccion = new TipoDireccion();
     $tipoDireccion->tipo = $tipo;
     return $tipoDireccion;
}
```

Because in the class definition, you define `private $tipo;` and then you try and assign `$tipoDireccion->tipo` to what was passed through the function.  However, you aren't trying to access that variable through the scope of the class, you are trying to assign it from the 'public' scope as far as the class is concerned.

The fix for this has two options, the first one would be to change `private $tipo;` to `public $tipo;`. But that isn't a good solution as you have an assignment function for it.

Instead, use your functions that you made, which would make the function look like:

```
function constructor1($tipo) {
     $tipoDireccion = new TipoDireccion();
     $tipoDireccion->ponTipo($tipo);
     return $tipoDireccion;
}
```

That's how you need to access it from the public scope, which you are doing after you initiate a new one.

Answer (score -1):

```
function constructor1($tipo) {}
```

should be

```
static function constructor1($tipo) {}
```

Comment: Thanks! I already tried that and it will still give me the same error

Comment: It is not correct answer to this question. Strict code format is not the problem for that error that OP has.